# \AtBeginShipoutInit macro of atbegshi causes weird behavior of opacity option in tikz with xelatex

Tags: transparency, atbegshi, bugs

Using `\AtBeginShipoutInit` causes the opacity option doesn't work at the first page properly, without that there is no problem with the code.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipoutInit
\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ]
    \node [color=black, scale=\textwidth/1cm, rotate=45, opacity=.2] at (current page.center) {draft};
\end{tikzpicture}
}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

first page will be:
[image]

and the second one: 
[image]

ps: 
As  Heiko Oberdiek said pdflatex and lualatex has no such an effect.

Comment: It works fine with `pdflatex` or `lualatex`, but I can reproduce the problem with `xelatex`.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek you are right, but I must use xelatex and I also need that macro.

Comment: The macro  `\AtBeginShipoutInit` is automatically executed at `\begin{document}`. What is the reason why you need it earlier? Maybe a compromise `\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutInit}` helps.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek thanks, it works with  `\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutInit}` but I am so confused why `\AtBeginShipoutInit` doesn't work correctly while as its manual said it should be executed at `\begin{document}`

Could you revise your answer with this solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem can be reproduced with `xelatex`. Removing the explicit `\AtBeginShipoutInit` helps:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ]
    \node [color=black, scale=\textwidth/1cm, rotate=45, opacity=.2]
    at (current page.center) {draft};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Other options are using `pdflatex` or `lualatex`.

Macro `\AtBeginShipoutInit` is automatically called at `\begin{document}`, if it is needed earlier, because the preamble contains some unknown code that requires it, then a compromise can be tried:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{atbegshi}

\AtBeginDocument{\AtBeginShipoutInit}

\AtBeginShipout{\AtBeginShipoutAddToBox{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, ]
    \node [color=black, scale=\textwidth/1cm, rotate=45, opacity=.2]
    at (current page.center) {draft};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}

% <unknown code>

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```